# Why are we able to write $A_{n}$ as $\bigcup_{x \in U^{c}} B(x, \dfrac{1}{n})$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was looking at this proof:

> Say $U$ is an open set. If $U$ is empty or if it is the whole space $X$ then $U$ is also closed, so we are done. Now assume that $U$ and its complement $U^c=X\setminus U$ are both non-empty.
>
> Let $A_n = \bigcup_{x\in U^c} B(x,\dfrac1n)$. Notice that $A_n$ is open and its complement $A_n^c$ (which is closed) is contained in $U$. To finish off the problem show that $U$ is the union of the $A_n^c$.

I wanted to know why we can write $A_{n}$ as $\bigcup_{x \in U^{c}} B(x, \dfrac{1}{n})$ when $U^{c}$ is a closed set?

Comment: $A_n$ is *defined* to be the above union. Is your question why this choice of $A_n$ works? For an answer to that, you should probably state the proposition in question.

Comment: They're defining  $A_n $ that way. I don't see any problem with  $U^c $ being closed. Note that  $U^c\subseteq A_n $.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou: think what I'm confused about is that $U^{c}$ is closed since we assumed that $U$ is an open set, but by definition of an open set, for every point $a$ in an open set, we can find $r$ so that the $B_{r}(a)$ is contained in this open set. But this property doesn't necessarily follow for closed sets?

Comment: @K.M. No one's making the claim that $A_n\subseteq U^c$. In fact, since $U^c$ is closed and neither empty nor all of $X$, this probably won't be true.

Comment: @K.M Yes, $B (x,1/n) $ may not be contained in $U^c $. But, it seems that the only crucial information the author needs is  $A_n^c\subseteq U $, which follows from my previous comment.